# Use of Service account credentials when using Cloud Functions Shell

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I've just migrated to Cloud Functions 1.0 and am trying out Cloud Functions shell/emulator to run functions locally (using instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator)

One of the functions is using code below to upload a file to cloud storage and then then generate url for it....but am getting following error:

> SigningError: Cannot sign data without `client_email`.

```
const bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);

bucket.upload(localFilePath, {destination: destinationPath})
    .then(data => {
      const file = data[0];
      return file.getSignedUrl({
        action: 'read',
        expires: '01-01-2099'
      });
```

I can work around this locally by explicitly setting `keyFileName` as shown below but seems like this should not be necessary

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({keyFilename: 'service-account.json'});
```

The link above mentions that "Cloud Firestore and Realtime Database triggers already have sufficient credentials, and do not require additional setup" (I'm triggering this code from db write).  I'm setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable in any case but doesn't look like it's picking it up.

Comment: Use of getSignedUrl requires a service account anyway.

Comment: @DougStevenson this issue is specific to when I use `firebase functions:shell` - it works ok when deployed.  Also I am calling `getSignedUrl` as per code in question.

Comment: I don't believe you can set arbitrary env vars to be used in the emulator.  That's managed by the CLI.

Comment: @DougStevenson what do you mean by "arbitrary env vars" in this case?  I guess putting it another way, what is recommended way of addressing this using Cloud Functions Shell.  All other functionality seems to be working file (and am setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as per instructions in the link I mentioned)

Comment: I had seen the question you marked this as duplicate of before....but I believe this issue is different and is related to running functions locally (and perhaps with use of v1.0).

Comment: The recommendation is to initialize the SDK with service account credentials from a file (as you already know works), or configure them using env vars that are specific to Cloud Functions for Firebase.  Don't try to set a shell env var.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env

Comment: I don't believe I'm trying to "set a shell env var"....the only env var I'm setting is GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to point to json file with service account info (as per https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).

Comment: That *is* a shell env var.  If you think there's a bug here, please file a bug report detailing the exact steps you're taking, and how it's not working the way you expect.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: If that's the case case doesn't "Don't try to set a shell env var" go against instructions in https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator  (in the "To set up admin credentials for emulated functions" section).  In any case,  will keep investigating here (and have reasonable workaround in meantime>

Comment: It's not the approach I would take to build functions that work both locally and deployed to Cloud Functions, as you don't have any control over the shell environment in the latter. I suppose if you only wanted to run locally, the env vat approach might be helpful, but if I was only going to run locally, I wouldn't be using Cloud Functions anyway.

Comment: "you don't have any control over the shell environment in the latter"....the point of my issue is that I'm trying actually to avoid having to do that....to *not* to have to set any local env vars/change code locally.  Rather I want to run functions locally and for them to use/have access to implicit vars that are set when run in cloud (and it seems use of `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is recommended way of providing that sort of "abstraction" when running locally...along with use btw of `firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json`).

Comment: Personally, I've never run into the need for that.

Comment: Hi @John. Did you ever find out how to get this to work? I am running the local emulators of the Cloud Functions & Firebase Storage now, but I got the same error "Cannot sign data without `client_email`" I already follow the instruction from the docs to `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/service-account.json"` but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue.